# How to specify dependencies using setuptools?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

My setupfile

```
setup(
  name = 'arkan',
  version = '1.0a',
  packages=find_packages(exclude=["contrib", "docs", "test*"]),
  install_requires=['demjson', 'simplejson', 'pytz', 'datetime', 'Request', 'urlopen']
)
```

I submitted to pypitest (https://testpypi.python.org/pypi). When i try to install my package using:

```
pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi arkan

Collecting arkan
.....
Collecting demjson(from arkan)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement demjson(from arkan) (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for demjson(from arkan)
```

I get same error for all the packages. I also tried adding version(`demjson>=2.2.0`) with no luck.

However, when I do pip install `demjson` from command line, it installs properly. I thought `install-requires` simply ran `pip install` on each of the dependency. Am i wrong in this?

I tried addding these dependencies on requirements.txt but `pip install` ignores the whole file completely.

How do I specify dependencies on my `setup.py` file so it gets properly installed?

Comment: `demjson` is likely just missing from the `testpypi` package index. If you install `demjson` (as well as your other dependencies) first, your package should be installable from `testpypi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears lot of packages such as `demjson` are missing in `testpypi` repo.